# Java equivalent to C#'s @ symbol for escaping \

Tags: c#, java, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java equivalent of C#'s verbatim strings with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673855/java-equivalent-of-cs-verbatim-strings-with)

An example in C# would be:

```
string path = @"C:\myfile.txt";
```

Another example is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-string-containing-backslashes-in-c) question.

Comment: `String path = "C:\\myfile.txt";`  Escape with another backslash.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673855/java-equivalent-of-cs-verbatim-strings-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String path = "C:\\myfile.txt";
// or "C:/myfile.txt";
// or "C:" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "myfile.txt";
```

Comment: yes, I know this, I meant, anything as convinient as @ rather than escaping with double \

Comment: I don't think so there is such thing in java

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing equivalent to the @ symbol in Java - you must escape each and every backslash in a String literal.

Comment: which makes sense... backslashes are, after all, a quite windows "centric" thing - forward slashes appear more often, I think (and you can actually simply replace backslashes with slashes)