# Why is my Web API server refusing to accept calls from Android?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, econnrefused

I can access my Web API server from a Windows app without problems. From Android, though, is [a different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797194/how-to-call-a-restful-method-from-android)

Why would that be?

Is "localhost" the wrong thing to use (in the URL)? Should I use the name of the computer instead?

Does the string (passed literally as "`http://localhost:28642/api/Departments/GetCount?serialNum=4242`")  need to be verbatimized?

What is the difference between a Windows app calling a REST method, and an Android app calling the same REST method, that would cause the latter to fail (connection refused)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencing "localhost" to refer to your local machine doesn't work on the Android emulator; you need to use a special IP which the emulator will forward on to the host machine. You need to replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/1217087).

If you're testing this on a physical device (rather than the emulator) you'll need to use your machines IP on the local network.