# Which Apache Commons IO jars do I need to add to my Android lib Folder?

Tags: java, jar, android-studio, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I've been turned on to the Apache IO package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818292/how-do-i-access-the-returned-value-from-a-web-api-method-in-android), so have downloaded it.

Yet, not wanting to clutter up my project with more stuff than I need, but simultaneously not wanting to omit necessary bits, I want to know just which jar file or files I need to add. There are several:

[image]

Based on what I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607552/How-to-add-external-library-file-in-Android-Studio), adding the .jar[s] should go smoothly, but which one[s] do I need?

Is commons-io-2.4.jar enough? Is commons-io-2.4-sources.jar enough? Both of them? Or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the `commons-io-2.4.jar` to use the library.

Explanation on the other ones

`commons-io-2.4-sources.jar`: sourcecode for `commons-io-2.4.jar`

`commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar`: documentation for `commons-io-2.4.jar`

`commons-io-2.4-tests.jar`:   tests for `commons-io-2.4.jar`

`commons-io-2.4-test-sources.jar`: sourcecode for `commons-io-2.4-tests.jar`