# Literal String using "@" in Java?

Tags: java, c#, string

In C#, there's a way to tell the compiler to interpret a `string` literally, without consideration of escape characters.

```
string myStr = @"Some literal string, \ doesn't need to be escaped";
```

Is something like this possible in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673855/java-equivalent-of-cs-verbatim-strings-with

Answer (score 4):

What you're referring to in C# is a *verbatim string literal*, as opposed to a *regular string literal* like `"foo"` - both are string literals, just as `"foo"` is a string literal in Java, too.

No, Java doesn't have any similar feature.

It also doesn't have any equivalent to the string interpolation feature being introduced in C# 6, with `"x={x} y={y}"` for example.