# In Java, is there a way to write a string literal without having to escape quotes?

Tags: java, string, escaping

Say you have a String literal with a lot of quotation marks inside it. You could escape them all, but it's a pain, and difficult to read.

In some languages, you can just do this:

```
foo = '"Hello, World"';
```

In Java, however, `''` is used for `char`s, so you can't use it for `String`s this way. Some languages have syntax to work around this. For example, in python, you can do this:

```
"""A pretty "convenient" string"""
```

Does Java have anything similar?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678483/simple-direct-heredoc-way-of-constructing-a-html-string-in-java

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/121513/403455) shows how to paste multi-line escaped strings in Eclispe.

Comment: Update 2018: raw string literals for Java might be coming. [See my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481601/6309)

Comment: import jackson ObjectMapper then 
  `System.out.println(mapperObj.writeValueAsString(mapperObj.readValue(str, Object.class)));`

Comment: update Q4 2018: raw string literal are *not* coming just yet. See my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481601/6309).

Comment: Coming back to this issue after away from java six years is irritating.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The answer is no, and the proof resides in the **Java Language Specification**:

```
  StringLiteral:
   "StringCharacters"

  StringCharacters:
   StringCharacter
   | StringCharacters StringCharacter

  StringCharacter:
   InputCharacter but not " or \
   | EscapeSequence
```

As you can see a `StringLiteral` can just be bound by `"` and cannot contain special character without escapes..

A side note: you can embed [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) inside your project, this will extend the syntax of Java allowing you to use `'''multi line string '''`, `' "string with single quotes" '` and also `"string with ${variable}"`.

Answer (score 168):

No, and I've always been annoyed by the lack of different string-literal syntaxes in Java.

Here's a trick I've used from time to time:

```
String myString = "using `backticks` instead of quotes".replace('`', '"');
```

I mainly only do something like that for a static field. Since it's static the string-replace code gets called once, upon initialization of the class. So the runtime performance penalty is practically nonexistent, and it makes the code considerably more legible.

Comment: wouldn't you need to use replaceAll?

Comment: @landon9720 No, .replace replaces all occurrences of a character/character sequence with another character/character sequence. .replaceAll uses regex.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know if the java compiler would simplify this upon compiling?

Comment: No, I don't think the compiler would simplify this. But it doesn't really matter. It's a very inexpensive call, and if I only do this for static final strings, the cost will only be incurred once, upon classloading. That's a price I'm usually willing to pay for nicer looking code :)

Comment: Then what about "\" in myString?

Comment: This is such a simple and yet fancy thing

Answer (score 22):

Since Java 15¹ there is new feature called Text Blocks. It looks similar to what you mentioned is available in Python:

```
String text = """
              {
                 "property": "value",
                 "otherProperty": 12
              }
              """;
```

More details with examples can be found here: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378 JEP 378: Text Blocks

---

¹ *Previewed in Java 13 and 14.*

Comment: Probably not THE correct answer but A possible answer depending on the reader and OP needs.

Answer (score 14):

Update Dec. 2018 (12 months later):

Raw string literals (which are on the [amber list](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/)) won't make it to JDK 12.
See the [criticisms here](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2018-December/002402.html).

---

There might be in a future version of Java (10 or more).

See [JEPS 8196004](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8196004) from January 2018: (["JEP" is the "JDK Enhancement Program"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Enhancement_Proposal))

> ### JEP draft: Raw String Literals
>
> Add a new kind of literal, a raw string literal, to the Java programming language.
> Like the traditional string literal, a raw string literal produces a String, but **does not interpret string escapes and can span multiple lines of source code**.

So instead of:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\foo\" bar");
String html = "<html>\n"
              "    <body>\n" +
              "         <p>Hello World.</p>\n" +
              "    </body>\n" +
              "</html>\n";
System.out.println("this".matches("\\w\\w\\w\\w"));
```

You would be able to type:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(`"C:\Program Files\foo" bar"`);
    
String html = `<html>
                   <body>
                       <p>Hello World.</p>
                   </body>
               </html>
              `;

System.out.println("this".matches(`\w\w\w\w`));
```

Neat!

But it is still [just a draft](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/1#Process-states): it will need to posted, submitted, be a candidate, and funded, before being completed and making it into the next JDK.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: No.

For longer strings that must be escaped, I usually read them from some external resource.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from apache commons

**UPDATE**: If someone is interested in some examples here is a useful link : https://dzone.com/articles/commons-lang-3-improved-and-powerful-StringEscapeUtils

Comment: Could you please add an example possibly based on the question illustrating how to it for this problem?

Comment: [It is considered suboptimal to only reference another resource that might answer the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) Please consider summarizing the linked page with an example matching the question.

Comment: I took a look and don't think either really answers the question.  The inputs to the static methods are `String`s, so no way to have a nicely formatted value in your code.  Presumably you could use these methods to read from a file into a `String`, but I don't think that's the question here.

Comment: The linked class (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils) has been deprecated and replaced with [org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

try StringTemplate

```
int var1=1;
System.out.println(STR."var1 = \{var1}");
```

will output into below

```
var1 = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use left and/or right quotes if you don't mind the difference, they look pretty similar:

```
"These “double quotes” don't need nor want to be escaped"
```

Answer (score -5):

The following seems to work for me:

```
String x = "Some Text" + '"' + "More Text" + '"' + "Even More Text";
```

I think because char is the primitive variable type for String, Strings and chars can be combined (at least the eclipse compiler doesn't seem to complain).

Comment: I think because char is the primitive variable type for String <- Your assumption is incorrect. For that matter, it will also work with a different type, like an int, like so: String x = "Some text" + 33 + "More text";