# How to enter quotes in a Java string?

Tags: java, string, quotes, escaping

I want to initialize a String in Java, but that string needs to include quotes; for example: `"ROM"`. I tried doing:

```
String value = " "ROM" ";
```

but that doesn't work. How can I include `"`s within a string?

Comment: Without escaping quotes version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034186/in-java-is-there-a-way-to-write-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-quote

Answer (score 271, accepted):

In Java, you can escape quotes with `\`:

```
String value = " \"ROM\" ";
```

Answer (score 20):

In reference to your comment after Ian Henry's answer, I'm not quite 100% sure I understand what you are asking.

If it is about getting double quote marks added into a string, you can concatenate the double quotes into your string, for example:

```
String theFirst = "Java Programming";
String ROM = "\"" + theFirst + "\"";
```

Or, if you want to do it with one String variable, it would be:

```
String ROM = "Java Programming";
ROM = "\"" + ROM + "\"";
```

Of course, this actually replaces the original ROM, since Java Strings are immutable.

If you are wanting to do something like turn the variable name into a String, you can't do that in Java, AFAIK.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure what language you're using (you didn't specify), but you should be able to "escape" the quotation mark character with a backslash: `"\"ROM\""`

Answer (score 15):

\ = `\\`

" = `\"`

new line = `\r\n` OR `\n\r` OR `\n` (depends on OS) bun usualy `\n` enough.

taabulator = `\t`

Comment: Down-vote from me. This answer doesn't help address the original question any more thoroughly than the existing answers posted a year before this.

Answer (score 12):

Just escape the quotes:

```
String value = "\"ROM\"";
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java, you can use char value with ":

```
char quotes ='"';

String strVar=quotes+"ROM"+quotes;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, you forgot the variable name. Also, your code is needlessly complex. This would do fine: `String foo = quotes + "ROM" + quotes;`. No need for all those extra `""`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is full **java** example:-

```
public class QuoteInJava {     

public static void main (String args[])
    {
            System.out.println ("If you need to 'quote' in Java");
            System.out.println ("you can use single \' or double \" quote");
    }
}
```

Here is Out PUT:-

```
If you need to 'quote' in Java
you can use single ' or double " quote
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look into this one ... call from anywhere you want.

```
public String setdoubleQuote(String myText) {
    String quoteText = "";
    if (!myText.isEmpty()) {
        quoteText = "\"" + myText + "\"";
    }
    return quoteText;
}
```

apply double quotes to non empty dynamic string. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This tiny java method will help you produce standard CSV text of a specific column.

```
public static String getStandardizedCsv(String columnText){

    //contains line feed ?
    boolean containsLineFeed = false;
    if(columnText.contains("\n")){
        containsLineFeed = true;
    }

    boolean containsCommas = false;
    if(columnText.contains(",")){
        containsCommas = true;
    }

    boolean containsDoubleQuotes = false;
    if(columnText.contains("\"")){
        containsDoubleQuotes = true;
    }

    columnText.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");

    if(containsLineFeed || containsCommas || containsDoubleQuotes){
        columnText = "\"" + columnText + "\"";
    }

    return columnText;
}
```

Comment: result of `columnText.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");` is ignored - needs to be `columnText = columnText.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");`

Answer (score -5):

suppose ROM is string variable which equals "strval"
you can simply do

```
String value= " \" "+ROM+" \" ";
```

it will be stored as

```
value= " "strval" ";
```

Comment: This does not answer the question any better that the accepted answer.  Please don't go adding answers to old questions like this.  It doesn't help.