# How to Save JSON in String variable using JAVA In Android?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i am newbie in android Here is JSON defined, i need to manually store  this JSON in String variable using JAVA in  Android.I am getting diffculty to do this.here is the code i have tried but its not correct.

```
 String jsonObject = "{


        {
                      "id": 22,
                      "menu_id": 1,
                      "field_type_id": 1,
                      "c4w_code": "1234",
                      "field_label": "Customer No",
                      "field_values": "",
                      "date_Created": "2012-09-16 05:11:23",
                      "date_modified": "2013-11-20 10:33:23",
                      "is_required": 0,
                      "is_static": 1,
                      "field_order": 1
        },
        {
                      "id": 23,
                      "menu_id": 1,
                      "field_type_id": 1,
                      "c4w_code": "1234",
                      "field_label": "Company Name",
                      "field_values": "",
                      "date_Created": "2012-09-16 05:11:56",
                      "date_modified": "2013-11-20 10:33:23",
                      "is_required": 1,
                      "is_static": 1,
                      "field_order": 3
        }

}";
```

i need to store it either in String or in JSONObject so that i can move a head to work with this.
after adding code :

```
MenuFields menuFieldInstance[];// an array of bean Class
Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonObjectString ="{\n\n\n {\n \"id\": 22,\n \"menu_id\": 1,\n \"field_type_id\": 1,\n \"c4w_code\": \"1234\",\n \"field_label\": \"Customer No\",\n \"field_values\": \"\",\n \"date_Created\": \"2012-09-16 05:11:23\",\n \"date_modified\": \"2013-11-20 10:33:23\",\n \"is_required\": 0,\n \"is_static\": 1,\n \"field_order\": 1\n },\n {\n \"id\": 23,\n \"menu_id\": 1,\n \"field_type_id\": 1,\n \"c4w_code\": \"1234\",\n \"field_label\": \"Company Name\",\n \"field_values\": \"\",\n \"date_Created\": \"2012-09-16 05:11:56\",\n \"date_modified\": \"2013-11-20 10:33:23\",\n \"is_required\": 1,\n \"is_static\": 1,\n \"field_order\": 3\n }\n\n}";
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
                menuFieldInstance = gson.fromJson(jsonObjectString,MenuFields[].class);
           for(int i=0;i<jsonObjectString.length();i++)
           {
               Log.i("menuField Instance ",""+menuFieldInstance[i].getId());
           }
        }
```

i am getting this logCat:

> 12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.survey.management.activity.MainActivity$RequestForCustomerMenuFields.getCustomerMenuFieldsData(MainActivity.java:480)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.survey.management.activity.MainActivity$RequestForCustomerMenuFields.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:456)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.survey.management.activity.MainActivity$RequestForCustomerMenuFields.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     ... 5 more
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>   12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):     ... 13 more

Comment: AFAIK, Java doesn't know multiline string literales.

Comment: can someone please guide me any tutorial so that i can store json in string or in jsonObject

Comment: First of all, it's not a valid JSON, try it at http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-string

Comment: read your error: "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT". Then read json specs: http://json.org

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to replace all your (double quotes) `" to \"` to compile the String object in java.

Use the below string:

```
String jsonObject ="{\n\n\n {\n \"id\": 22,\n\"menu_id\": 1,\n \"field_type_id\": 1,\n\"c4w_code\": \"1234\",\n\"field_label\": \"Customer No\",\n\"field_values\": \"\",\n\"date_Created\": \"2012-09-16 05:11:23\",\n\"date_modified\": \"2013-11-20 10:33:23\",\n\"is_required\":0,\n\"is_static\": 1,\n\"field_order\": 1\n},\n{\n\"id\":23,\n\"menu_id\": 1,\n\"field_type_id\": 1,\n\"c4w_code\": \"1234\",\n\"field_label\": \"Company Name\",\n\"field_values\": \"\",\n\"date_Created\": \"2012-09-16 05:11:56\",\n\"date_modified\": \"2013-11-20 10:33:23\",\n\"is_required\": 1,\n\"is_static\": 1,\n\"field_order\": 3\n}\n\n}";
```

Comment: i am getting this exception when trying to put it in  my Bean Array Class : 12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
12-30 22:56:47.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2238):  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
the code i have added in edit please see this.

Comment: remove first and last bracket i.e'{' and replace it by '['

Comment: And put the json in one single line.

Answer (score 1):

**Worked like a charm!!!**

```
String jsonObject="{   {\"Filter\": \"No\",\"Data Type\": \"Aggregated\", \"Key-Fields\": \"Application IP, Client IP, Protocol, Application Port, Client Port\",\"Metric-fields\": \"Bandwidth, Packets\", \"Filter\":\"Enable\"   } }";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace all your doublequote (") with (\") and it will work.