# Create a Java String variable with string formatting

Tags: java, string, variables, string-formatting

I need to create a String variable . that should be like following variable.

> String search = "**xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />**";

but I cannot assign **xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />** directly into a String variable because  **tempuri.org/" />";** get commented automatically.

I need a format this string and finally  variable should be like this

> search  = xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /> ;

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use escape characters:

```
String search = "xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />";
```

Version from the comments:

```
String search = "xmlns=\"tempuri.org/\"; /></soap:Body>";
```

Comment: Actually I need following String assign to a variable. Could you please modify the answer according to this

xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap:Body>

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the special chars i.e replace the **"** for **\"**

```
String search = "xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />";
```

Comment: Actually I need following String assign to a variable. Could you please modify the answer according to this,