# what does this \ symbol means in javascript used to inject in webview android

Tags: java, android

i found a code in internet 
**code is :**
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.color=\"white\";");

**My question is :**
what does \ symbol mean and do in the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559063/115145

Comment: oh its a escape sequence .thank u for ur answer

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two completely separate languages. Make up your mind whether you want advice about JavaScript or about Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The \ symbol in programming languages is used to escape an char, which would create conflicts in the text.

For Example, if you want to print out **My nickname is "Tom"**, the codeline would be

```
System.out.println("My nickname is "Tom"");
```

The compiler see only the part of "My nickname is" and failes then
So, the correct solution is

```
System.out.println("My nickname is \"Tom\");
```

So the compiler recognizes, that "Tom" is part of the text. This works in nearly all programming languages with the \
If you want to write a \ in your string, you have to escape it to with backslash, so it becomes \ \ .

Hope i helped :)