# How can i print my name with double quotes in java

Tags: java

can i use some diffrent method to print "you" i.e within double quotes.
I am giving code System.out.println("you");
and it is giving output you 
What should i do to make my output "you" i.e within double quotes

Comment: Or also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string

Answer (score 3):

You can include a literal quote by escaping it with a backslash:

```
System.out.println("\"you\"");
```

Comment: okay thank you Sir

Answer (score 1):

Use **\"** in double quotes to print **"**

```
System.out.println("\"Madhuri Anandani\"");
```