# How to replace a quoted number to number format in a string

Tags: java

I have a String in Java, something like this -

```
{elementId:'pagination',locale:'en',activePage:'1',items:'-10',maxButtons:'5'}
```

I need the numbers without the quotes

```
{elementId:'pagination',locale:'en',activePage: 1, items: -10, maxButtons:5}
```

Tried

```
 replaceAll("\\d+", "$0") or 
 replaceAll("[0-9]", "$0")
```

But it returns me number with quotes.

Is there a way to remove these quotes for numbers?

Comment: Is that a string? Or is it a map of strings -> strings?

Comment: So you have a JSON and you want to deserialize it ?

Comment: this is a JSON object which I convert to string format and then write to a file.
@JFPicard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Comment: That's a JSON. You can find many JSON libraries for Java to parse them *correctly*.

Comment: I don't want to use a Parser, is there any other alternative? @Koshinae

Comment: Yes, making your own.

Answer (score 0):

If `{elementId:'pagination',locale:'en',activePage:'1',items:'-10',maxButtons:'5'}` is a string as you've said, you could use the String.replace method. As such: `foo.replace("'","");`
this method returns a string with all instances of ' replaced.

Comment: OP wants to the quotes only for numbers not throughout the string

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need elementId:'pagination',locale:'en',activePage: 1,items:-10,maxButtons: 5 
so replacing all " ' " will also replace the text values for elementId:'pagination',locale:'en'. I don't want that