# How to remove ":" from String in java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a String which contains characters in the sequence : **":"**

Instead of that, I just need: **:**

Like this:
Original:

```
"Value**":"**One"
```

Chages I need:

```
"Value : One"
```

What operation I should do on String like replaceAll to get the required output?

Comment: Looks like broken JSON. Better fix input at the sender.

Comment: @Fildor I thought too but it would still requires `: {` not `{`

Comment: @AxelH It's just a suspicion on my behalf. There is not enough info to really tell where the exact problem is and how to deal with it, IMHO.

Comment: Ya,one of the String contains same sequence and that's now solved because of answer below.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape " in order to remove them

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("{\"\":", "");
```

**EDIT**

After you asked another question using this one, you should do, assuming you want to replace **":"* * (whitespace between * is for avoid bold font)

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("**\":\"**", ":");
```

Comment: 1) `replace` is enough, your are replacing a fixed string, 2) it is advisable to use `yourString = yourString.replace(...)` to point out the fact that strings are immutable in Java.

Comment: Since the string in question looks like bad JSON, I would suggest to fix the issue where it happens: At the sender.

Comment: As the character sequence in the question is changed now, the accepted answer is doing totally different.

Comment: @procrastinator already edited, thanks for the notice