# How to pass double quoted strings through sendKeys method using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, double-quotes

I am working on a selenium script where 3 values are being fetched and store in String.

```
String one = "19292";
String two = "Abc";
String three = "def";
```

I want it to send text as (one + two + three) but all of them is having double quotes. So end result should be `"19292""Abc""def"`

How can I do this ?

I have tried using the escape mechanism using back slash, but whenever I use it rather than fetching the string value it prints the text.
For Eg :

```
\"one\" prints "one" rather than "19292"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sth like this:

```
field.sendKeys("\"" + one + "\"\"" + two + "\"\"" + three + "\"");
```

I just checked with selenium and it works. The input which goes to field is :
"19292""Abc""def"

Or if you don't know the number of Strings then below is the method which will convert in quotes format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String one = "19292";
    String two = "Abc";
    String three = "def";

    System.out.println(surroundWithDoubleQuotes(one, two, three));


}

public static String surroundWithDoubleQuotes(String... input) {
    if(input == null || input.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String arg : input) {
        builder.append("\"\"");
        builder.append(arg);
    }
    builder.append("\"");
    builder.deleteCharAt(0);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: field.sendKeys("\"" + one + "\"\"" + two + "\"\"" + three + "\""); 
This worked. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = "\"" + one + "\"\"" + two + "\"\"" + three + "\"";
```

Comment: I can't edit the string value. It is being fetched from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String str = "\""+one+"\"\""+two+"\"\""+three+"\"";
System.out.println(str);
```

This will print `"19292""Abc""def"`

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to pass the resultant string as **`"19292" "Abc" "def"`**, then definitely the following *Strings* declarations won't help the purpose:

```
String one = "19292";
String two = "Abc";
String three = "def";
```

Instead you need to do the following:

```
String one = " \"19292\" ";
String two = " \"Abc\" ";
String three = " \"def\" ";
```

An example to send the strings as **`"19292" "Abc" "def"`**with the *textbox* of [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          String one = " \"19292\" ";
          String two = " \"Abc\" ";
          String three = " \"def\" ";
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q"))).sendKeys(one + two + three);
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: quoted_string_sendKeys]

Comment: I am not declaring the strings. They are fetched from a file. So i can't edit them