# MySQL Java deleting row based on two string columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is the line

```
PreparedStatement delete = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName +" WHERE first LIKE " + firstName + " AND last LIKE " + lastName);
```

I want to check if both the first name and the last name match the query before i delete the row.
'first' and 'last' are both columns in my table.
I am getting this error message

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: Hendrix)
```

In this case Hendrix is the value for `lastName`.

Why does last LIKE ____ not work in this case? Is there another keyword i should use if i am checking
multiple strings?

Comment: You need to quote the strings. Also if they are exact matches, use = rather than like.

Answer (score 0):

[In Java, you can escape quotes with \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string#answer-3559079):

```
PreparedStatement delete = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE first = \"" + firstName + "\" AND last = \"" + lastName + "\"");
```

Of course, i find that a bit hard to read, so I prefer to mix my single and double quotes rather than escape them:

```
PreparedStatement delete = con.prepareStatement('DELETE FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE first = "' + firstName + '" AND last = "' + lastName + '"');
```

As for your question on LIKE.  [Try reading up on the difference between LIKE and =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like/28609966).  There is a lot of information out there on it.  In short...LIKE is for use with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the prepared statement the way it is intended, with placeholders for the values and then binding the values afterwards with `setString` you wouldn't have this problem. Try this instead:

```
PreparedStatement delete = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName +" WHERE first LIKE ? AND last LIKE ?");
delete.setString(1, "%" + firstName + "%");
delete.setString(2, "%" + lastName + "%");
delete.executeUpdate();
```

Note that to use `LIKE` you need to include the `%` in the value being bound. If you want to compare exact values, you would use this instead:

```
PreparedStatement delete = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName +" WHERE first = ? AND last = ?");
delete.setString(1, firstName);
delete.setString(2, lastName);
delete.executeUpdate();
```