# Apache POI, Formulas True and False

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Need to finish my project for college, decided to do it in JAVA with APACHE for excel, just to learn something more, anyway.

I've created formula:

```
sheet.getRow(i).createCell(4, CellType.FORMULA).setCellFormula("IF(B:B=1800, TRUE, IF( B:B< 1800, FALSE))");
```

The question is:
Is there any possibility to change TRUE and FALSE for any other words ?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't really get your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In excel i'm able to change TRUE for PAID and FALSE for NOT PAID, however can't do it formula, because I Can't use double Quote in formula:

=IF(B:B=1800,"PAID",IF(B:B<1800,"NOT PAID"))       - taken from excel

Need to create something like this

Comment: what you are really asking is how to [escape quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad This did work ! Thank you very much. As I said, It's my first semester in software development, still a lot to learn. Once again, thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)