# get String between two Chars (two Quotes)

Tags: java, string, double-quotes

i'm trying to get the Text between two quotes with this code. But i have got only the first text "nice day". Please help ...

Text input:

```
 Today is a „nice day“  and i „like“  it because because of the „sun and flowers“ .
```

Code:

```
public static String getStringBetweenTwoChars(String input, String startChar, String endChar) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
                if (start != -1) {
                    int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());
                    if (end != -1) {
                        String x = input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
                        input = input.substring(end + 1);
                        return  x;
                    }


                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There are so many problems. Some of them are: (1) You need to change the return type from `String` to `void`; because a function can return only one value (2) You do not need `try...catch` block. (3) The parameters `startChar` and `endChar` are unnecessary/ambiguous etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to split input and read only odd index.

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sin = "Today is a \"nice day\" and i \"like\" it because because of the \"sun and flowers\".";
        System.out.println(sin);
        String[] s=sin.split("\"");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
            if(i%2==1) System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Today is a "nice day" and i "like" it because because of the "sun and flowers".
nice day
like
sun and flowers
```

Update on posted code:

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sin = "Today is a \"nice day\" and i \"like\" it because because of the \"sun and flowers\".";
        String sout = Split.getStringBetweenTwoChars(sin, "\"", "\"");
        System.out.println(sout);
    }

    public static String getStringBetweenTwoChars(String input, String startChar, String endChar) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Input-Length: " + input.length());
                int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
                if (start != -1) {
                    int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());

                    System.out.println("Das sind: " + end);
                    if (end != -1) {
                        String x = input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
                        input = input.substring(end + 1);

                        System.out.println("RestText: "+input);
                        System.out.println("QuoteText: "+x);
                        String snext=getStringBetweenTwoChars(input, "\"", "\"");
                        if(snext!=null)
                            x=x+","+snext;
                        return  x;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Today is a "nice day" and i "like" it because because of the "sun and flowers".
Input-Length: 79
Das sind: 20
RestText:  and i "like" it because because of the "sun and flowers".
QuoteText: nice day
Input-Length: 58
Das sind: 12
RestText:  it because because of the "sun and flowers".
QuoteText: like
Input-Length: 45
Das sind: 43
RestText: .
QuoteText: sun and flowers
Input-Length: 1
nice day,like,sun and flowers
```

Update for array

```
//let method signature as it is
String sout = Split.getStringBetweenTwoChars(sin, "\"", "\"");
//remove comma and get result into array
String[] s=sout.split(",");
```

Comment: @ Traian: Thank you for your feedback. But do you know: why is my code not work?

Comment: Yes, use recursivity and get all results ... Updated

Comment: Ok, but with your code we have to change the original input-text with "/". If we have to input a very long text with 1000 dopple-quotes then is your code not effective. Let's see the solution of Krustibat from above is better.

Comment: NO. Method signature it's the same as you added ! Just added recursion. Local string is just for test purpose ! Add input string from where you wanted Text File, Locally  have no importance since it's keep original signature. Try it !

Comment: `Input-Length: 79` -> count it ! for `Today is a "nice day" and i "like" it because because of the "sun and flowers".` (this is what is processed-> can be obtain in various mode.Important is that is method is sending the right string !). Check also, maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string

Comment: `But do you know: why is my code not work`  : Yes, use recursivity and get all results ... (didn't say that is the Only fix ... it's a solution). What's the down-side of recursivity ... another story ! ... any-way look again on first version and others and choose what think it's best fit !

Comment: Ok, special thanks. It work very well. But with this code  --> x=x+","+snext; i will get at output a String: "nice day,like,sun and flowers".  How can i become a array like: ["nice day", "like", "sun and flowers"] ?

Comment: Yes, but have to modify method signature from `String` to `String []`. My advice is to return a `List` (and then do whatever ... place into array elements, etc) ... Another option very easy without any changes is `String[] arr = returnStringWithComma.split(",");` ... Good Luck !

Comment: Hi, i have changed it with modify method signature from String to String [] (please see below) but it not work.

Comment: Yes, recursivity means auto-invoke and can cause some issues (can be fixed also). Easiest way is let metdod signature and code as it is and just process String with coma ... check update

Comment: Hi. Now i've got that thing! So i'v used this code: String[] s=sout.split(","); and then: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)); DONE!

Answer (score 2):

````
        String res = "";
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Input-Length: " + input.length());
                int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
                if (start != -1) {
                    int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());

                    if (end != -1) {
                        String x = input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
                        input = input.substring(end + 1);
                        res += x;
                    }


                }

            }
            return res;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; 
    }```
````

Comment: Hi Krustibat. I have new Idea: I want me to get an array at the output. So i've changed the code below: But I don't become a Array. Could you tell me, what i do wrong? (Please see the Code below)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to target those phrases inside the quotes:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String startChar = "\"";
    String endChar = "\"";

    String input = "Today is a \"nice day\" and i \"like\" it because because of the \"sun and flowers\".";
    String pattern = startChar + "([\\s\\w]*)" + endChar;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just split it by quotation marks, and the only go after the odd numbered elements in the resulting array:

```
String str = "Today is a \"nice day\" and i \"like\" it because because of the \"sun and flowers\".";
String[] parts = str.split("\""), res = new String[parts.length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res[i] = parts[i * 2 + 1];
}

return res;
```

Note that this returns an array of strings, not just one string, so you may have to adjust your return type.