# Programmatically move to a new line within a cell in .csv file through an Android application in Java

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-external-storage, android-storage

I am creating a .csv file from my Android application and storing the data in .csv format. However, when the length of a particular cell's value exceeds a certain number of characters, it leaves that cell and moves to a completely new row towards the first column. How can I display within the same cell?

Here is the code I am using to create and save data in .csv format from my android application.

```
public class ReportListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CREATE_FILE:
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    if (uri != null) {
                        new ExportCSV(this).execute(uri);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_listing);



    private void createFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/csv");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "stored_data.csv");


        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
    }

    private class ExportCSV extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Boolean> {
        private final WeakReference<Context> context;

        ExportCSV(Context c) {
            context = new WeakReference<>(c);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
            Uri uri = uris[0];
            Context c = context.get();


            if( c == null ) {
                return false;
            }

//updated code
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.append("Flight Number, Departure Date, Comments");

String first_comment = "hello this is an example of the comments that I am talking about in this case. If I keep typing it will move to the next row which i do not want at all. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";

String second_comment = "It is long and it moves" + "\n" + "to the first column and subsequent rows";

pre_comments1 = "1) " + first_comment  + "\n";
pre_comments2 = "2) " + second_comment + "\n";

pre_comments_consolidated = pre_comments1 + pre_comments2;

data.append("\n" + flightNumber + "," + departureDate + ","+ pre_comments_consolidated);

//until here
            try {
                OutputStream os = c.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                if(os!=null) {
                    os.write(data.toString().getBytes());
   
                    os.close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**Below is a screenshot of the output I am getting when I open the csv file in Excel**

The text from Column3 moves to Column1 and subsequent rows when the text is too long or when it has new line characters (\n). How can I fix it and just display it within the same cell i.e. Column3?

[image: excel output]

The second image shows the new output when I use double quotes on my variables to append data to my csv file.

[image: New output when I use double quotes on my variables to append data to my csv file]

Comment: [This page](https://www.excelchamp.net/adding-line-breaks-in-a-csv-file/) says you need to quote the entries containing line breaks. As in `data.append("\"Hello\nworld\"")`.

Comment: What if I want to pass in a variable?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Moreover, even when the String doesn't contain a line break, it goes to the first column and subsequent rows.

Comment: `What if I want to pass in a variable?` You can join strings with other things using `+`. Verify the output in something simple, like Notepad. Excel isn't reliable unless you use the *Data > Import from CSV* function. The image in your question doesn't match the code, so it's impossible for me to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have updated the code and image and now they are same, the code matches the output, so could you please help with there? Thanks! :)

Comment: @EugenPechanec where do I exactly place the quotes that you were referring to in the first comment?

Comment: If you want a line break to be part of the value, you need to quote the value _inside the string_ - wrap _the value_ in `"`. Don't get it confused with quotes you need to produce strings in Java. Example: `"\"This\nwill\nbe\na\nmultiline\nvalue\""` Note the escaped quotes (`\"`) within the outer string quotes.

Comment: You may also want to simplify you strings for reading, example `"1) " + "hello" + "\n";` is actually just `"1) hello\n"`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have updated the code above, and that is exactly how it is in my application. Basically, I have strings stored as variables. Where exactly do I place the quotes so that I can get line break within same call in css file?

Comment: Wrap the values in quotes. You CSV looks like this: `String csv = "some value, other value\nwith line break";` It needs to look like this: `String csv = "\"some value\",\"other value\nwith line break\"";`. [This may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229058/discussion-between-ian-bell-and-eugen-pechanec).

Comment: @EugenPechanec
For my application, the first_comment string and the second_comment string, I am getting it from a database, hence I am not declaring the string anywhere in the activity.
The long string in the first_comment and second_comment string variable comes from my Rooms database directly and hence I am not hardcoding the strings. 
So where do I place the double quotes in the code?

Comment: `So where do I place the double quotes in the code?` Around the CSV values. It's not important if the value is hardcoded or from database. You know where you put the CSV values together, so add the quotes at the same time.

Comment: When I wrap the values in quotes to the place where I am putting my csv values together, it just prints the variable name as a string. here is the code ` data.append("\n" + "\"flightNumber\"" + "," + "\"departureDate\"" + ","+ "\"pre_comments_consolidated\""); `. In the excel file, it prints flightNumber, departureDate and pre_comments_consolidated as values. I am adding the screenshot of the output in the question above.

Comment: @EugenPechanec how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `"\n" + "\"" + flightnumber + "\""` and `"\n" + "\"" + "flightnumber" + "\""`?

Comment: I see, its more clear now, thanks a lot! The first one uses the value of the variable flightnumber and the second one prints flightnumber itself as a string.

Comment: Thanks a ton @EugenPechanec , your help solved the issue I was facing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between

```
"\n" + "\"" +  flightnumber  + "\""
```

and

```
"\n" + "\"" + "flightnumber" + "\""
"\n" + "\"flightnumber\""
"\n\"flightnumber\""
```

For better readability, and since `StringBuilder` is already used to concatenate strings, here's everything on a separate line:

```
data.append("Flight Number");
data.append(',');
data.append("Departure Date");
data.append(',');
data.append("Comments");
data.append('\n');
// ...
data.append(flightNumber);
data.append(',');
data.append(departureDate);
data.append(',');
data.append('"' + pre_comments_consolidated + '"');
```

Notes:

- Put single characters in single quotes : `'\n'`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`
- You don't have to escape double quotes inside single quotes and vice versa: `"'"`, `'"'`
- You can concatenate characters and strings: `"example" + '\n'`
- You're joining *literal* double quotes with *variable* `pre_comments_consolidated`.

This will not work properly if the CSV *value* contains quotes. You'll need to [*CSV-escape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv) them. You should consider putting all that logic in a separate function.

```
private String escapeCsv(String in) {
    // Double double quotes that are already part of the value.
    String out = in.replace("\"", "\"\"");
    // Wrap the whole thing in double quotes.
    return '"' + out '"'
}
```

Use like this:

```
data.append(escapeCsv(pre_comments_consolidated));
```

Be mindful of

- which quotes you need to denote a Java string,
- which quotes you need printed literally,
- which quotes need escaping (either in Java or in a format down the line, like CSV).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help is greatly appreciated and solved my problem! :)