# Printing quotes in java

Tags: java, html, string

I need to make a string with the following content:

```
<head>    
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, meta tags, metadata" />
</head>
```

Because of all of the quotation marks, not all of the words are included.

Comment: Show us how you are trying to output that String.

Comment: Escape your double-quotes.  [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Google the title of your question, and click the [first result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3844595/778118).

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: thanks so much rgettman you just saved my project

Comment: Read it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: *"thanks so much rgettman you just saved my project"* ... Oh, I doubt that.

Comment: @user3170404 No, I didn't just save your project.  I just referred you to well-known tutorials on well-known, basic Java knowledge about escape characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this

```
String str = "<head>\n<meta name=\"keywords\" "
    + "content=\"HTML, meta tags, metadata\" />\n</head>";
System.out.println(str);
```

Which outputs

```
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, meta tags, metadata" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can escape the individual quotations:

```
<head>    
<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"HTML, meta tags, metadata\" />
</head>
```