# Printing, reading, operators

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am supposed to get an output like the following:

Type in your first name: John

```
Hi, "John"
The name of this exercise is 'Modifying printing'.
Tabulator, line change and quotations have already been used in this exercise.
Backward slash (\) is also usable in printing.
```

**End of exercise**

But I couldn't get the name part, John, within `" "`. Please any one help me. My code looks as follows:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class apples {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s;
String m;
Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type in your first name: ");
s= reader.nextLine();
m="Forward slash (\\) is also usable in printing.";
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Hi, "+s);
System.out.println("\tThe name of this exercise is 'Modifying printing'.");
System.out.println("\tTabulator, line change and quotations have already been used in   this exercise.");
System.out.println("\t"+m);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("\t\t*** End of exercise ***");
}
}
```

---

Comment: Are you asking how to **escape** `"`?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the `"`?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I make Java print quotes, like "Hello"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3844595) (also a good reference for how you should've asked your question)

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape character `\`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Hi, \"%s\"",s));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println("Hi, \"" + s + "\"");
```

where \ is used to escape the following ".

search for "escaping characters in java" in your favourite search engine.

Have fun getting started with Java!

Comment: No problem! In fact you already escaped a char in your code! Check the line `m="Forward slash (\\) is also usable in printing.";` ;-)

Comment: @user3314727 this question still appears as unresolved. could you please mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert a `"` character in a string, you have to prepend a `\` to mark it as non-string-terminating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the ".

To do that you use the \ character.

So if you want to print Hello "John", you could do `System.out.println("Hello \"John\"")`;