# Print Console in Application JavaFX

Tags: javafx, console

as the title said i want to show the console log to the user of my application

I come with this

```
package utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Log {

public static void checkLog(TextArea txt) throws IOException {

    Console console = new Console(txt);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.setErr(ps);

    for (char c : "some text".toCharArray()) {
        console.write(c);
    }
    ps.close();
}

public static class Console extends OutputStream {

    private TextArea output;

    public Console(TextArea ta) {
        this.output = ta;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        output.appendText(String.valueOf((char) i));
    }
}
}
```

And i put the thing in

```
TextArea txt = new TextArea();
Log.checkLog(txt);
Scene scene = new Scene(txt, 700, 500);
```

when i clic on my button to show my stage with my TextArea in it ... the only thing that i see is : "some text" without quote ...

But what i want is all my System.out.print

Did i miss something ?

Thanks for your answer ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Java print quotes, like "Hello"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello); also [How to enter quotes in a Java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559063/how-to-enter-quotes-in-a-java-string)

Comment: So show me where is your duplicate question maybe ?  @James_D

So there is no duplicate ... can someone answer me ...

See my edit maybe you don't understand my question

Thanks

Comment: Could someone remove the [duplicate] flag plz ...

Just look my title 

"Print Console in Application JavaFX" 

it's not like 

"How can I make Java print quotes, like “Hello”? "

Comment: Why block my question when it's not a duplicate ?  @fabian ?

Comment: The part about redirecting `System.out` to a `TextArea` has been asked somewhere too. I voted for close in the first place, since you're asking why characters that aren't even in the string are not written to the  stream, which IMHO is sufficiently similar to the dupe.

Comment: Totally unclear what you're asking then. What are you trying to do? You need to [edit] the question to make it clearer what you mean. The code you posted will clearly just display the text *some text* in the text area; if you want something different to that, you need to explain what you want and post code that shows an attempt to do it.

Comment: more clear than that : "But what i want is all my System.out.print" ? ... thanks anyway ..

Comment: You just don't read my post until the end, nevermind, i don't understand this treatment.

Comment: So now how to get help for that problem ? You locked it ... and if i start a new one i'm afraid someone block it too...

Did i should post my question in a nearly similar subject ? 

I don't understand this kind of treatement, i read the FAQ and my question was clear enough ...

So should i start a new Question ?
or add a comment in a similiar question ?