# Change email javascript regex to java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I need to parse the email header (from, to) from gmail api and separate it example: "John Doe " become name: "John Doe" and email: "john.doe@gmail.com". I already found the solution, however it is in javascript. I need to convert it to java code. I have problem in change javascript regex to java:

```
const regex = /(([\w,\"\s]+)\s)?<?([^@<\s]+@[^@\s>]+)>?,/g;
```

This is my regex in java:

```
String regex = "(([\\w,\\"\\s]+)\\s)?<?([^@<\\s]+@[^@\\s>]+)>?";
```

I try to remove the first '/' and ',/g' character and also replace all '\' with '\\' character but still get error in regex.

This is not a duplicate of [Print Hello Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello)  because the problem is with matching the characters in the regex and not printing them. I already know about "\"" make " in java.

Comment: `\\"` will have a backslash in the string, then terminate the string. In order for regexp engine see `\"`, your Java String literal needs to be `\\\"`. That said, `\"` is useless, since `"` doesn't need to be escaped for regexp; `"` suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` too, otherwise it closes the String.
`"(([\\w,\\\"\\s]+)\\s)?<?([^@<\\s]+@[^@\\s>]+)>?"`

As Amadan said, `"` does not require escaping in regex, so it can be `"(([\\w,\"\\s]+)\\s)?<?([^@<\\s]+@[^@\\s>]+)>?"`