# How can i save a String with double quotes from Java's scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, quotation-marks

The user input a String through the scanner and the format of String is `"Testing"` (quoted with `“”`) .
Just like `C:\> "Testing"`

I'd like to save the text as a String without double quotes. How do I catch the text in the middle of quotes?

Comment: You can escape quotation marks with a backslash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Java print quotes, like "Hello"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello)

Comment: Do you want to remove all the quotes, or get the string in the double quotes and discard what is not? What should happen when there is no quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Please lookup basic Java string manipulation.

A few approaches in Java:

1. Use .substring(1, length-1)
2. Use .replaceAll(“\”,””)
3. Use regular expression in Java and extract contents between “(.*)”

Show us what you’ve tried

Answer (score 0):

If the double quotes are always present at the start and end 
Then

```
s= s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
```

else you can try

```
if(s.charAt(0)=='"'){
       s=s.substring(1,s.length());
   }
   if(s.charAt(s.length()-1)=='"'){
       s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
   }
```