# Is there an alternative way to generate quote marks without using the escape sequence?

Tags: java, escaping, sequence, quotations

I am trying to get my output to display double quotations around the abbreviations and also the translated abbreviations.  However I have not covered escape sequences in my current class so I was wondering if there was another way to accomplish this.  The workbook will not accept when I try with escape sequence.

I have tried escape sequence and using two single quotes ('' '') but neither have worked.  Perhaps I am missing something and am fairly new to the java language.  Just trying to learn the most efficient way from a fundamental standpoint.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgExpander {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

String txtMsg;
String BFF = "best friend forever";
String IDK = "I don't know";
String JK = "just kidding";
String TMI = "too much information";
String TTYL = "talk to you later";

System.out.println("Enter text: ");
txtMsg = scnr.nextLine();

System.out.println("You entered: " + txtMsg);
System.out.println();

if(txtMsg.contains("BFF")) {
  txtMsg = txtMsg.replace("BFF", BFF);
  System.out.println("Replaced BFF with " + BFF);
}                    // above line is where I tried escape sequence

if(txtMsg.contains("IDK")) {
  txtMsg = txtMsg.replace("IDK", IDK);
  System.out.println("Replaced IDK with " + IDK);
}

if(txtMsg.contains("JK")) {
  txtMsg = txtMsg.replace("JK", JK);
  System.out.println("Replaced JK with " + JK);
}

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Expanded: " + txtMsg);

return;
```

}
}

Your output

Enter text: 
You entered: IDK how that happened. TTYL.

Replaced IDK with I don't know
Replaced TTYL with talk to you later

Expanded: I don't know how that happened. talk to you later.

Expected output

Enter text: 
You entered: IDK how that happened. TTYL.

Replaced "IDK" with "I don't know".
Replaced "TTYL" with "talk to you later".

Expanded: I don't know how that happened. talk to you later.

Comment: [Is this what you've previously tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello)

Comment: There are other ways of doing this, including using a StringBuilder and appending the `"` character, but the most efficient way is to use the `\ ` escape character: `\"` is how you escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
\"example text\"
```

So you would have something like this:

```
  System.out.println("Replaced \"BFF\" with " + "\"" + BFF + "\"");
```

or

```
  System.out.println("Replaced \"BFF\" with \"" + BFF + "\"");
```

Comment: I apologize to all who helped the previous attempt with escape sequence I formatted improperly however this worked this time.  Thank you all for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work with escape characters. 
Have u tried something like this:

```
 System.out.println("\"These two semi colons are removed when i am printed\"");
```

I tested it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `\` escape sequences, for whatever reason, you can use the fact that an `'` apostrophe doesn't need to be escaped in a `"xx"` string literal, and that a `"` double-quote doesn't need to be escaped in a `'x'` character literal.

E.g. to print `Replacing "foo" with 'bar' was easy`, and `foo` and `bar` are from variables, you can do this:

```
String s = "Replacing " + '"' + foo + '"' + " with '" + bar + "' was easy"`;
```