# How should I replace \" on the "

Tags: java, string, replace, java-8

For example I have code like this

```
String text = "\\\"";
String after = text.replaceAll("\"", "\"") // I want to see " but have \"
```

How can I replace "\ on the " with replaceAll() ?

Comment: can you try this `text.replace("\\", "");`

Comment: There is no reason to use a regular expression for this.  `text.replace("\\\"", "\"")` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question it can be

`String after = text.replaceAll("\"", "")`.

But you have two different questions in title and post.

Maybe try read this first
[How can I make Java print quotes, like "Hello"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello)

Comment: the question from my understanding is how to unescape quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong argument for the matcher. You need to escape both the `\` as well as `"` in your regular expression.

`\\` is the back slash and `\\\"` is the quotation mark.

```java
String after = text.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
```

alternatively you can also just drop the backslash as per @bharathp's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Matcher.quoteReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)). Its definition states:

> Slashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) will be given no special meaning.

Example:

```
String text = "\\\"";
System.out.println("before replaceAll: " + text);
String after = text.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"), "");
System.out.println("after replaceAll: " + after);
```

Output:

```
before replaceAll: \"
after replaceAll: "
```