# Using quotes in a java string

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, spigot

I am using Java 17, Maven, and i am still learning, my question is why does

```
String database= ""database"";
```

output as

```
'"database"'
```

i want it to output as "database" but when i do

```
String database = ""database"" it wont work.
```

it just outputs it with extra " or ' added. i need the output to just be 'database' or "database" with quotes included but i cannot get it to work.

I have tried to escape the quotes, using methods i have found online, nothing is working. I am doing this for a minecraft plugin config that keeps outputting wrongly, here is an example.

```
database:
  host: host
  port: 3306
  database: '"database"'
  username: username
  password: password
```

i need it to be

```
database:
  host: host
  port: 3306
  database: "database" or 'database'
  username: username
  password: password
```

Comment: `String database= ""database"";` will not compile.

Comment: you have to escape the quotes https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844602/8843585

Comment: This looks rather about YAML than Java. `"'database'"` or `'"database"'` should work. Why do you need the quotes though?

Comment: Escape with back-slash `String database= "\"database\"";`

Comment: @K-Galalem then i am getting the output database: '"database"', keep in mind it is outputting to a config.yml file.

Comment: @knittl just for personal preference, i would like them there. Although when i escape quotes i get the output database: '"database"', keep in mind it is outputting to a YAML file but from one of my java classes as it is saving the default for my config.

Comment: @Mxzzy I'm not sure I understand: "for personal preference" – does the value require quotes or not? If quotes can't be there, you can't put them there – they will break stuff. If they must be there, then it's not personal preference. How does your YAML and your Java program come together? How are you using the value from the YAML file?

Comment: @knittl i want the '' there to connect the value if there is any spaces, it works because i have manually edited the config and used them, the java program is a minecraft plugin that connects to mysql, the database connection string is in this config and i want to have quotes surrounding the last 3 values as a user has requested that.

Comment: `'"database"'` will not work, but use ` as delimiter (as used in phpmyadmin for example) can work too

Answer (score 1):

Is it Java code though? if you want to print quotes in Java, use [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character):

```
String javaCodePrintQuotes = "\"database\"";
```