# How to write SQL statement with quotes?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, is there a way to write a string literal without having to escape quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034186/in-java-is-there-a-way-to-write-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-quote)

I want to get Oracle starttime with sql query. I use this SQL statement

```
SQL_Statement = "select to_char(startup_time, 'HH24:MI DD-MON-YY') "Startup time" from  v$instance";
```

There is a problem with the quotes when I try to write a code with this SQL statement. What is the proper way to write this SQL statement?

Best wishes

P.S I use Java. When I try to run this SQL query:

```
select  to_char(startup_time, 'HH24:MI DD-MON-YY') 'Startup time' from  v$instance
```

I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select  to_char(startup_time, 'HH24:MI DD-MON-YY') 'Startup time' from  v$instance 
Error at Command Line:1 Column:50
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: try replacing the double quotes inside the string with single quotes. you're unintentionally closing your SQL query string.

Comment: plus, please show more research effort next time.. a simple search on google or stackoverflow would've flooded your browser with this same answer.

Comment: @user1103606 - What language are you using to interact with the database?  That language will have some way to escape double quotes inside a string.  My guess is that using a single `\` before the embedded double quotes will work but that's a guess without knowing the language you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, you need to escape the double quotes inside the string using a single '\' character

```
SQL_Statement = "select to_char(startup_time, 'HH24:MI DD-MON-YY') \"Startup time\" from  v$instance";
```

See [escaping double quotes in a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034186/in-java-is-there-a-way-to-write-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-quote)

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes (') when inside double quotes (") for all strings.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select q'{This string's got some extra "quotes" in it}' from dual;
```

Can use {} or [] or whatever floats your boat (thats not in your string of course).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you distinguish between the differences of the single and double quotations within SQL statements

[What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)