# Insert to table column string value containing ' ' '

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to insert a value to table column  and the string contains '  '  ' in it. For eg.   Al'aK  and how to do this in sql server 2008 r2?

All that for doing it from asp.net and I am trying to do it sql itself.

Insert into @table values('Al'ak',1)

Comment: This is a very basic question and you can easily find this on Google.

Comment: Look up how to escape a single quote, and you will learn that you should use two single quotes instead of one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write SQL statement with quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673427/how-to-write-sql-statement-with-quotes)

Comment: Its in the front end and I am searching for back end itself as part of a procedure

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ' with '' and insert

```
create table #tab(id int,value varchar(50))

insert into #tab values(1,'Alka''s')
select * from #tab
```