# Do You Need To Escape * Character in Java?

Tags: java, string, split, escaping, wildcard

So I wrote a little section of code in a program of mine that uses the split method to parse out and sort the individual components held within a string. Below is a sample of the code:

```
String[] sArray;

String delimiter = "*";

String test = "TEXT*TEXT*TEXT*";
String a = "";
String b = "";
String c = "";

sArray= test.split(delimiter);

a = sArray[0];
b = sArray[1];
c = sArray[2];

System.out.println("A is: " + a + "\nB is: " + b + "\nC is: " + c);
```

However, when I run this program, it returns an error stating that:

`Dangling meta character '*' near index 0`

So I googled this error and found it might be related to an issue with how `*` can be considered a wildcard character in regex. So I tried:

`String delimiter = "\*"`

But that just returned another error stating:

`illegal escape character`

Has anyone ran into this issue before or know how you are (if you are) supposed to escape `*` in java?

Comment: Note (Jan. 2018), raw string literals might be coming for Java (JDK 10 or more): see [In Java, is there a way to write a string literal without having to escape quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481601/6309).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You also have to escape the backslash:

```
String delimiter = "\\*";
```

Because the string literal `"\\"` is just a single backslash, so the string literal `"\\*"` represents an escaped asterisk.

Answer (score 5):

The way to understand the solution is to realize that there are two "languages" in play here.  You have the language of regular expressions (Java flavour) in which `*` is a meta-character that needs to be escaped with a `\` to represent a literal `*`.  That gives you

```
''\*''    // not Java yet ...
```

But you are trying to represent that string in the "language" of Java String literals where a `\` is the escape character.  So that requires that any literal `\` (in whatever it is we are trying to represent) must be escaped.  This gives you

```
"\\*"     // now Java ...
```

If you apply this approach/thinking consistently - "first do the regex escaping, then do the String literal escaping" - you won't get confused.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to attach "\" before "*" as if you want to represent "\" in java you have to use one more "\" before it.

So, "\" represents:-----> "\"
So if you want to use "*" as delimiter the use "\*"

Corrected Code:

```
String delimiter = "\\*";
String test = "TEXT*TEXT*TEXT*";
String a = "";
String b = "";
String c = "";
sArray= test.split(delimiter);
a = sArray[0];
b = sArray[1];
c = sArray[2];
System.out.println("A is: " + a + "\nB is: " + b + "\nC is: " + c);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> A is: TEXT
>
> B is: TEXT
>
> C is: TEXT