# How I can write SPARQL query that uses similarity measures in Java Code

Tags: java, sparql, jena, similarity

I would like to know a simple method to write this SPARQL query in Java Code:

```
select ?input
       ?string
       (strlen(?match)/strlen(?string) as ?percent)
where {
  values ?string { "London" "Londn" "London Fog" "Lando" "Land Ho!"
                   "concatenate" "catnap" "hat" "cat" "chat" "chart" "port" "part" }

  values (?input ?pattern ?replacement) {
    ("cat"   "^x[^cat]*([c]?)[^at]*([a]?)[^t]*([t]?).*$"                              "$1$2$3")
    ("Londn" "^x[^Londn]*([L]?)[^ondn]*([o]?)[^ndn]*([n]?)[^dn]*([d]?)[^n]*([n]?).*$" "$1$2$3$4$5")
  }

  bind( replace( concat('x',?string), ?pattern, ?replacement) as ?match )
}
order by ?pattern desc(?percent)
```

This code is contained in the discussion [To use iSPARQL to compare values using similarity measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557020/to-use-isparql-to-compare-values-using-similarity-measures/24558392?noredirect=1#comment38069096_24558392).
The purpose of this code is to find the resources similar to a given word on DBPedia.
This method takes into consideration that I know in advance the strings and the length of it. I would like to know how I can write this query in a parameterized method that, regardless of the word and the length of it, it returns to me the similarity measures.

Comment: Do you already have the pattern part (e.g., `^x[^cat]*([c]?)[^at]*([a]?)[^t]*([t]?).*$`, or do you need to generate that in Java code from `"cat"`?

Comment: I need to generate that in Java code from "cat" or from another words

Comment: That's all you need to do, right?  There are plenty of questions here that already show how to run queries against DBpedia from Jena, including some of your earlier questions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/24606539/1281433.

Comment: You've already shown that you know how to use parameterized SPARQL strings in Jena, so it seems like you're just asking how to get the pattern from the input.  That's not a specific technical question though.  Have you written any code to try?   It seems like it's pretty simple string processing.  What problem did you run into?  Until you show what you've tried, and explain what's going wrong, this is off topic for Stack Overflow, as "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must…

Comment: … include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: My question is: given the word "cat" I have to take "cat", then the "at", then "t". If my word were "children", I have to take "children", then "hildren," then "ildren", then "ldren," then "dren", then "ren", then "en", then "n". Right?
I have not tried yet to implement, but I assume that this is done through an iteration of substrings of the word. But I believe that in this way the code becomes expensive, complex and unreadable. Is there a solution that is not expensive, is not complex and is not unreadable?

Comment: By "in java code", do you wish to retrieve the data from Jena using pure java mechanisms (ie: no SPARQL), or do you mean that you wish to implement a custom property-function or filter-function that will be called by the query evaluation system?

Comment: @RobHall  OP's previous questions (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/24606539/1281433) show the ability to run queries from Java.  I *think* the question here is how to generate a pattern like `^x[^cat]*([c]?)[^at]*([a]?)[^t]*([t]?).*$` from the string `cat`.   I like your property function approach though, because if someone's got a more efficient similarity metric already, a property function might be a nice way to compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** [ARQ - Writing Property Functions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_propfuncs.html) is now part of the standard Jena documentation.

It looks like you'd enjoy having a syntactic extension to SPARQL that performs the more complex portions of your query. For example:

```
SELECT ?input ?string ?percent WHERE
{
   VALUES ?string { "London" "Londn" "London Fog" "Lando" "Land Ho!"
                    "concatenate" "catnap" "hat" "cat" "chat" "chart" "port" "part" }

   VALUES ?input  { "cat" "londn" }

   ?input <urn:ex:fn#matches> (?string ?percent) .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?percent)
```

In this example, it's assumed that `<urn:ex:fn#matches>` is a property function that will automatically perform the matching operation and calculate the similarity.

The Jena documentation does a great job explaining how to [write a custom filter function](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_functions.html), 
but (as of 07/08/2014) does little to explain how to implement a custom property function.

I will make the assumption that you can convert your answer into java code for the purpose of calculating string similarity, and focus on the implementation of a property function that can house your code.

**Implementing a Property Function**

Every property function is associated with a particular `Context`. This allows you to limit the availability of the function to be global or associated with a particular dataset.

Assuming you have an implementation of `PropertyFunctionFactory` (shown later), you can register the function as follows:

***Registration***

```
final PropertyFunctionRegistry reg = PropertyFunctionRegistry.chooseRegistry(ARQ.getContext());
reg.put("urn:ex:fn#matches", new MatchesPropertyFunctionFactory);
PropertyFunctionRegistry.set(ARQ.getContext(), reg);
```

The only difference between global and dataset-specific registration is where the `Context` object comes from:

```
final Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.createMem();
final PropertyFunctionRegistry reg = PropertyFunctionRegistry.chooseRegistry(ds.getContext());
reg.put("urn:ex:fn#matches", new MatchesPropertyFunctionFactory);
PropertyFunctionRegistry.set(ds.getContext(), reg);
```

***MatchesPropertyFunctionFactory***

```
public class MatchesPropertyFunctionFactory implements PropertyFunctionFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertyFunction create(final String uri)
    {   
        return new PFuncSimpleAndList()
        {
            @Override
            public QueryIterator execEvaluated(final Binding parent, final Node subject, final Node predicate, final PropFuncArg object, final ExecutionContext execCxt) 
            {   
                /* TODO insert your stuff to perform testing. Note that you'll need
                 * to validate that things like subject/predicate/etc are bound
                 */
                final boolean nonzeroPercentMatch = true; // XXX example-specific kludge
                final Double percent = 0.75; // XXX example-specific kludge
                if( nonzeroPercentMatch ) {
                    final Binding binding = 
                                BindingFactory.binding(parent, 
                                                       Var.alloc(object.getArg(1)),
                                                       NodeFactory.createLiteral(percent.toString(), XSDDatatype.XSDdecimal));
                    return QueryIterSingleton.create(binding, execCtx);
                }
                else {
                    return QueryIterNullIterator.create(execCtx);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Because the property function that we create takes a list as an argument, we use [`PFuncSimpleAndList`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/pfunction/PFuncSimpleAndList.html) as an abstract implementation. Aside from that, most of the magic that happens inside these property functions is the creation of `Binding`s, `QueryIterator`s, and performing validation of the input arguments.

***Validation/Closing Notes***

This should be more than enough to get you going on writing your own property function, if that is where you'd like to house your string-matching logic.

What hasn't been shown is input validation. In this answer, I assume that `subject` and the first list argument (`object.getArg(0)`) are bound (`Node.isConcrete()`), and that the second list argument (`object.getArg(1)`) is not (`Node.isVariable()`). If your method isn't called in this manner, things would explode. Hardening the method (putting many `if-else` blocks with condition checks) or supporting alternative use-cases (ie: looking up values for `object.getArg(0)` if it is a variable) are left to the reader (because it's tedious to demonstrate, easily testable, and readily apparent during implementation).

Comment: It might be good to point out that the `(?string ?percent)` notation isn't anything special to property functions, but is part of the syntax, and is shorthand for `[ rdf:first ?string ; rdf:rest [ rdf:first ?percent ; rdf:rest rdf:nil ] ]`.

Comment: +1 Great answer, would you consider writing a [documentation patch](http://www.apache.org/dev/cmsref#non-committer) for the Jena website that covers this?