# How to add " " quotes around printed String?

Tags: java, string, printing

I want to print inverted quotes in java. But how to print it?

```
for(int i=0;i<hello.length;i++) {
    String s=hello[i].toLowerCase().trim();
    System.out.println(""+s+"");
}
```

expected  OP:  "hi".....

Comment: Please search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2018583/166390

Comment: The question here asks for **inverted** quotes, which is not a duplicate of the links above.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because double quotes *delimit* String values, naturally you must escape them to code a literal double quote, however you can do it *without* escaping like this:

```
System.out.println('"' + s + '"');
```

Here, the double quote characters (`"`) have been coded as `char` values. I find this style easier and cleaner to read than the "clumsy" backslashing approach. However, this approach may only be used when a *single* character constant is being appended, because a 'char' is (of course) exactly one character.

Answer (score 16):

As quotes are used in the Java source code to represent a string, you need to escape them to create a string that contains a quote

```
 System.out.println("\""+s+"\"");
```

Answer (score 4):

You must escape the quotes: `\"`

Comment: s/must/could/p .... there are other alternatives

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "Inverted" quotes you meant "Left" and "Right" specific quotation marks, you could do it like this:

```
System.out.println('\u201C'+s+'\u201D'); // Prints: “s”
System.out.println('"'+s+'"');           // Prints: "s"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are really looking for **inverted** quotes, use this:

```
System.out.println('\u201C' + s + '\u201D');
```

It'll output `“hi”`, not `"hi"`.

You need to have a font installed, though, that supports this, otherwise you might get a box or something instead. Most Windows fonts do.